# Linking Lists in SharePoint 2010 programatically

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation, dropdown

How would I link two lists so that one pulls in a set of data from another and populates a dropdown list in the first list for you to select from.

Example:

- List A contains a drop down called fruit.
- List B contains a column (field) called name with names like apple, banana, passion

> List A's drop down should pull from List B and populate its drop down
>   using the contents of "name" from List B.

How would I do this programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a [Lookup Column](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/create-list-relationships-by-using-unique-and-lookup-columns-HA101729901.aspx). The column can be created and configured in the UI, via Powershell, or via [code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff717837%28v=office.14%29.aspx).